# PHP word censor with keeping the original caps

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

We want to censor certain words on our site but each word has different censored output.

For example:

PHP => P*P, javascript => j*vascript

(However not always the second letter.)

So we want a simple "one star" censor system but with keeping the original caps. The datas coming from the database are uncensored so we need the fastest way that possible.

```
$data="Javascript and php are awesome!";

$word[]="PHP";
$censor[]="H";//the letter we want to replace

$word[]="javascript";
$censor[]="a"//but only once (j*v*script would look wierd)
//Of course if it needed we can use the full censored word in $censor variables
```

Expected value:
**J*vascript and p*p are awesome!**

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: do you have the list of censored words?

Comment: No not yet. We will have the full list later.

Comment: Should word `javascript` be replaced when word `javascriping` or `javascripted` is used?

Comment: Yes Glavic, we want to censor all matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your censored words in key-based array, and value of the array should be the position of what char is replaced with `*` (see `$censor` array example bellow).

```
$string = 'JavaSCRIPT and pHp are testing test-ground for TEST ŠĐČĆŽ ŠĐčćŽ!';

$censor = [
    'php' => 2,
    'javascript' => 2,
    'test' => 3,
    'šđčćž' => 4,
];

function stringCensorSlow($string, array $censor) {
    foreach ($censor as $word => $position) {
        while (($pos = mb_stripos($string, $word)) !== false) {
            $string = 
                mb_substr($string, 0, $pos + $position - 1) . 
                '*' . 
                mb_substr($string, $pos + $position);
        }
    }
    return $string;
}

function stringCensorFast($string, array $censor) {
    $pattern = [];
    foreach ($censor as $word => $position) {
        $word = '~(' . mb_substr($word, 0, $position - 1) . ')' . mb_substr($word, $position - 1, 1) . '(' . mb_substr($word, $position) . ')~iu';
        $pattern[$word] = '$1*$2';
    }
    return preg_replace(array_keys($pattern), array_values($pattern), $string);
}
```

Use example :

```
echo stringCensorSlow($string, $censor);
# J*vaSCRIPT and p*p are te*ting te*t-ground for TE*T ŠĐČ*Ž ŠĐč*Ž!

echo stringCensorFast($string, $censor) . "\n";
# J*vaSCRIPT and p*p are te*ting te*t-ground for TE*T ŠĐČ*Ž ŠĐč*Ž!
```

---

Speed test :

```
foreach (['stringCensorSlow', 'stringCensorFast'] as $func) {
    $time = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
        $func($string, $censor);
    }
    $time = microtime(true) - $time;
    echo "{$func}() took $time\n";
}
```

output on my localhost was :

```
stringCensorSlow() took 1.9752140045166
stringCensorFast() took 0.11587309837341
```

---

**Upgrade #1:** added multibyte character safe.

**Upgrade #2:** added example for [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), which is faster than [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php). Tnx to [AbsoluteƵERØ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145800/absoluteer)

**Upgrade #3:** added speed test loop and result on my local PC machine.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I really like your position based idea. Please let me make some speed test before I accept anything, because brbcoding's answer is looking good too.

Comment: This is a pretty cool way to do it. Should be slightly faster than mine too I'd imagine. +1'd

Comment: Ha, they are pretty close -- [Yours](http://3v4l.org/fhGc8/perf#tabs) -- [Mine](http://3v4l.org/Ef45E/perf#tabs)

Comment: @brbcoding : your can be even faster if you remove `if` statement in your `censorWord()` function. @martincpt : both of our examples will not work with multibyte characters...

Comment: That's true. I only kept it there because it would need it as a standalone function, but in this example, it's not needed.

Comment: I tested all the possible solutions you posted guys and Glavic's method was the faster. AbsoluteƵERØ's answer was pretty elegant, but it has no multibyte-caps support, only if mb-caps are matched. Thanks Glavic!

Comment: @martincpt Something strange. In Glavićs for testing I had to replace the `[]` with `array()` probably a short tags setting. When I drop in my test phrase in Cyrillic for a side-by-side speed comparison, the code partially works in Glavić's. Also note the speed difference. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q2a-dff

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ : `[]` is the [shortened array syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for php>=5.4. Output is different, because your code outputs `JavaScripts` as `J*v*Scripts` and my as `J*vaScripts`. There is speed difference; and the speed will decrease with more text, so regular expression replace is better. I have added regular expression example to the answer.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I tested Glavić's code without multibyte on my server and that was faster at me. I think that was the first he posted before any edit. Your code was faster with multibyte but as I mentioned before there were problems with the caps. But I'll test these fixed scripts again when I have a little time and thanks again for these much help. Btw I dont understand why they downvoted my question, was it that noob?

Answer (score 2):

Make an array of words and replacements. This should be your fastest option in terms of processing, but a little more methodical to setup. Remember when you're setting up your patterns to use the `i` modifier to make each pattern case insensitive. You could ultimately pull these from a database into the arrays. I've hard-coded the arrays here for the example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<?php

$word_to_alter = array(
'!(j)a(v)a(script)(s|ing|ed)?!i',
'!(p)h(p)!i',
'!(m)y(sql)!i',
'!(p)(yth)o(n)!i',
'!(r)u(by)!i',
'!(ВЗЛ)О(М)!iu',
);

$alteration = array(
'$1*$2*$3$4',
'$1*$2',
'$1*$2',
'$1$2*$3',
'$1*$2',
'$1*$2',

);

$string = "Welcome to the world of programming. You can learn PHP, MySQL, Python, Ruby, and Javascript all at your own pace. If you know someone who uses javascripting in their daily routine you can ask them about becoming a programmer who writes JavaScripts. взлом прохладно";

$newstring = preg_replace($word_to_alter,$alteration,$string);

echo $newstring;

?>

</html>
```

**Output**

> Welcome to the world of programming. You can learn P*P, M*SQL, Pyth*n,
> R*by, and J*v*script all at your own pace. If you know someone who
> uses j*v*scripting in their daily routine you can ask them about
> becoming a programmer who writes J*v*Scripts. взл*м прохладно

**Update**

It works the same with UTF-8 characters, note that [you have to specify a `u` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to make the pattern treated as UTF-8.

> u (PCRE_UTF8)
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This
> modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP
> 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really elegant way and it was really fast. However multibyte strings didn't work with different caps. I'd suggest this solution for everybody who need multibyte support without care about the caps. Thanks again!

Comment: @martincpt I've updated the answer to show how to use UTF-8 matching. I didn't see the request in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a little helper function and pass it a word and the desired censor?

```
function censorWord($word, $censor) {
    if(strpos($word, $censor)) {
        return preg_replace("/$censor/",'*', $word, 1);
    }
}
echo censorWord("Javascript", "a"); // returns J*avascript
echo censorWord("PHP", "H"); // returns P*P
```

Then you can check the word against your wordlist and if it is a word that should be censored, you can pass it to the function. Then, you also always have the original word as well as the censored one to play with or put back in your sentence.

This would also make it easy to change the number of letters censored by just changing the offset in the `preg_replace`. All you have to do is keep an array of words, explode the sentence on spaces or something, and then check `in_array`. If it is in the array, send it to `censorWord()`.

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qaDGt3)**

And here's a more complete example doing exactly what you said in the OP.

```
function censorWord($word, $censor) {
    if(strpos($word, $censor)) {
        return preg_replace("/$censor/",'*', $word, 1);
    }
}

$word_list = ['php','javascript'];
$data = "Javascript and php are awesome!";
$words = explode(" ", $data);
// pass each word by reference so it can be modified inside our array
foreach($words as &$word) {
    if(in_array(strtolower($word), $word_list)) {
        // this just passes the second letter of the word
        // as the $censor argument
        $word = censorWord($word, $word[1]);    
    }
}

echo implode(" ", $words); // returns J*vascript and p*p are awesome!
```

**[Another Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OFl775)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please let me make some speed test between your and Glavic's code, so I can decide which to accept.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a lowercase list of the censored words somewhere, and if you're okay with starring the second letter every time, do something like this:

```
if (in_array(strtolower($word), $censored_words)) {
    $word = substr($word, 0, 1) . "*" . substr($word, 2);
}
```

If you want to change the first occurrence of a letter, you could do something like:

```
$censored_words = array('javascript' => 'a', 'php' => 'h', 'ruby' => 'b');
$lword = strtolower($word);
if (in_array($lword, array_keys($censored_words))) {
    $ind = strpos($lword, $censored_words[$lword]);
    $word = substr($word, 0, $ind) . "*" . substr($word, $ind + 1);
}
```

Comment: Maybe have the array be 2d, and store the index of the censored letter with each word?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. Create a simple database (text file) and make a "table" of all your censored words and expected censored results. E.G.:

   ```
   PHP --- P*P
   javascript --- j*vascript
   HTML --- HT*L
   ```
2. Write PHP code to compare the database information to your simple censored file. You will have to use `array explode` to create an array of only words. Something like this:

   ```
   /* Opening database of censored words */
   $filename = "/files/censored_words.txt";
   $file = fopen( $filename, "r" );

   if( $file == false )
   {
       echo ( "Error in opening file" );
       exit();
   }

   /* Creating an array of words from string*/
   $data = explode(" ", $data); // What was "Javascript and PHP are awesome!" has
                                // become "Javascript", "and", "PHP", "are", 
                                // "awesome!". This is useful.
   ```
3. If your script finds matching words, replace the word in your data with the censored word from your list. You would have to delimit the file first by `\r\n` and finally by `---`. (Or whatever you choose for separating your table with.)

Hope this helped!